# A program that accepts numbers and computes their sum, and displays smallest and largest number

Tags: c++, beginner, c++14

I am self learning programming by reading "Programming: Principles, and Practice" by Bjarne Stroustrup. I have solved a drill. Please review my code and give suggestions.

**Drill**

> Write a program that:
>
> - Accepts numbers with units m, cm, ft, and in and rejects other units.
> - Keeps a record of all the numbers in a single unit and computes the      sum of the numbers.
> - Prints the smallest and the largest numbers.

**My solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double temp{0};
    string temp_unit;
    vector<double> numbers;
    double sum{0};

    constexpr double cm_to_m = 0.01;
    constexpr double ft_to_m = 0.3048;
    constexpr double in_to_m = 0.0254;

    cout<<"Enter an integer with its unit. E.g 2m or 2 m \n";
    while(cin>>temp>>temp_unit){
        if(temp_unit=="m"){
            numbers.push_back(temp);
        }
        else if(temp_unit=="cm"){
            numbers.push_back(temp*cm_to_m);
        }
        else if(temp_unit=="ft"){
            numbers.push_back(temp*ft_to_m);
        }
        else if(temp_unit=="in"){
            numbers.push_back(temp*in_to_m);
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Incorrect Unit\n";
        }
    }
    sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
    for(auto& i:numbers){
        cout<<i<<" ";
        sum+=i;
    }
    cout<<"\nNumber of elements "<<numbers.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum of numbers: "<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"Smallest number: "<<numbers[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Largest number: "<<numbers[numbers.size()-1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use maps to handle mappings

instead of having constants for each individual ratio, you might as well have a single constant that holds both the ratios and their respective strings, as well as being able to map one to the other.

Consider this:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, double> unit_ratios = {
  {"m", 1.0},
  {"cm", 0.01},
  {"ft", 0.3048},
  {"in", 0.0254}
};

int main() {
  std::vector<double> numbers;

  double temp;
  std::string temp_unit;
  while(cin>>temp>>temp_unit){
    try {
      numbers.push_back(temp * unit_ratios.at(temp_unit));
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range&) {
      cout<<"Incorrect Unit\n";
    }
  }
...
}
```

Doesn't that look nicer? all the names and ratios nicely bundled together in one spot.

That's also why I've set it as a global constant in my example: The ratios and their name have nothing to do with the main function, they just are, so they should exist out of context.

### Declare variables as late as possible

`double sum{0};` should be declared as close as possible to the first use.

### Use algorithms when possible.

You can use `std::accumulate` to calculate the sum:

```
double sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0);
```

### Use front() and back() to access the first and last elements of a vector

You could make an argument that `numbers[0]` is as good as `numbers.front()`, but not for the last element.

```
cout<<"Smallest number: "<< numbers.front() << endl;
cout<<"Largest number: "<< numbers.back() << endl;
```

### Do you really need to sort?

Sorting is a O(NlogN) operation, whereas `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` are both O(N).

Since you are only doing these two lookups through the vector, you might be better off just using these instead.

If you can use c++11, then `std::minmax_element` is even better, since you only have to do one pass.

## don't use using namespace std;

Just... just don't. Please see every other C++ question on this site as to why.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a search function that finds N elements based on N predicates, and return an `std::array<iterator, N>` with the iterators to found elements? I just believe that `std::minmax_element` can be generalized. I'm not able to implement it at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: @Incomputable Not a bad idea. I would definitely not bother doing this for pre-c++17 at this point, as my gut feeling is that fold expressions would make this trivial to implement.

Comment: @Incomputable: Here you go: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180925/generalizing-stdminmax-element, as I expected, it's pretty simple using fold expressions.

Answer (score 4):

No need to keep the entire array and sort it. Instead compute the value as you go:

```
double sum{0};
double min{0};
double max{std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()};
int count = 0;

while(cin>>temp>>temp_unit){
    if(temp_unit=="m"){
        //left empty
    }
    else if(temp_unit=="cm"){
        temp = (temp*cm_to_m);
    }
    else if(temp_unit=="ft"){
        temp = (temp*ft_to_m);
    }
    else if(temp_unit=="in"){
        temp = (temp*in_to_m);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Incorrect Unit\n";
        continue;
    }
    sum+=temp;
    if(min > temp) min = temp;
    if(max < temp) max = temp;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: And yet you still push on `temp_unit == "m"` :P.

Comment: Also, the exercise states that the numbers should be kept: *"__Keeps a record of all the numbers__ in a single unit and computes the sum of the numbers."*

Answer (score 2):

`cm_to_m`, `ft_to_m` and `in_to_m` sound like functions rather than ratios. If you make them functions then you don't need to remember to multiply at the call site.

```
constexpr double cm_to_m(double cm) { return cm * 0.01;   }
constexpr double ft_to_m(double ft) { return ft * 0.3048; }
constexpr double in_to_m(double in) { return in * 0.0254; }
```