# Generalizing std::minmax_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

In the following [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/180899/128454), @Incomputable basically dared me to implement a generalization of `std::minmax_element`.

> Have you thought about creating a search function that finds N elements based on N predicates, and return an std::array with the iterators to found elements? I just believe that std::minmax_element can be generalized.

I'm happy to oblige:

```
#include <array>

template<typename IteT, typename... PredsT>
auto multi_search_elements(IteT begin, IteT end, PredsT const&... preds) {
    const std::size_t count = sizeof...(PredsT);
    std::array<IteT, count> selected;

    selected.fill(begin);
    if(begin != end) {
      for(++begin; begin != end; ++begin) {
        std::size_t i = 0;
        ( (selected[i] = preds(*selected[i], *begin) ? selected[i] : begin, 
           ++i), ...);
      }
    }

  return selected;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vals = {1,2,3,4,5};

  auto found = multi_search_elements(vals.begin(), vals.end(), std::less<int>(), std::greater<int>());

  for(auto i : found) {
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I understand this fold expression might look like voodoo to people who are not used to that type of code, so I'll elaborate on what's going on here for those of you who are curious:

The fold expression looks like this: `(EXPR, ...)`, which will expand to `EXPR, EXPR, EXPR, etc...`, where the "binary" operator used is actually the comma operator, which effectively just sequences the expressions while leaving them unrelated.

After that, all I do is make `EXPR` be `SUB_EXPR, ++i`, so the whole thing expands as:

```
(SUB_EXPR, ++i), (SUB_EXPR, ++i), (SUB_EXPR, ++i), (SUB_EXPR, ++i), ...
```

Which is essentially:

```
selected[i] = preds_0(*selected[i], *begin) ? selected[i] : begin,
++i,
selected[i] = preds_1(*selected[i], *begin) ? selected[i] : begin,
++i,
selected[i] = preds_2(*selected[i], *begin) ? selected[i] : begin,
++i,
selected[i] = preds_3(*selected[i], *begin) ? selected[i] : begin,
++i
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really good. Thank for trying it out!

Comment: Well, *min* and *max* are 1) based on a total ordering and 2) mutually exclusive as soon as there are two distinct values.

Comment: @greybeard I apologize, I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: Part of the fun of `minmax_element()` is needing 3n/2 comparisons instead of 2n.

Comment: Ah! Yes, of course. Yeah, this idea here is not to replace minmax_elements, just expand on the semantics. You are right to point that out.

Answer (score 3):

This code is pretty good, and there's very little to improve.  The two-line fold expression did benefit from the explanatory comment in the description, so perhaps it could get a summary in the code?

I found a couple of very minor simplifications:

- We can declare `count` as

  ```
      static const auto count = sizeof...(PredsT);
  ```
- Instead of duplicating `++begin` in a `for` loop, we can transform to a simpler `while` loop:

  ```
      while (++begin != end) {
  ```
- Instead of indexing `selected`, we might choose to iterate (and avoid a no-op assignment, and avoid the need to remember precedence of comma operator):

  ```
      auto p = selected.begin();
      ((preds(**p, *begin) ? *p++ : *p++ = begin), ...);
  ```

Comment: Your fold expression looks a million time better than mine, but I worry about the value of p in the call to preds. I can't test right now, but iirc it's not clear when the incrementation should happen in that case.

Comment: I did originally have `++p` outside the `?:` expression as you did; just moved it inside because I never remember the precedence of `,` (I do actually know it's lower precedence, but it's like there's implicit grouping of the middle argument).  I'm pretty sure there's an ordering of side-effects at the `?`.

Comment: In case that's not clear: I had `(*p = (preds(**p, *begin) ? *p : begin, ++p), ...)` working happily