# Find the oldest person by Lithuanian National Identification Number

Tags: c++

I made a program which parses the [NIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Lithuania) from kodai.txt file and calculates the oldest woman and man and outputs their DOB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;

enum Genders {
    Man, Woman      
};

struct Person {
    Genders gender;
    int dobYear;
    int dobMonth;
    int dobDay;
    long code;  
};

Person parsePerson(long kodas) {
    Person person;

    kodas = kodas / 10000;
    int firstNumber = kodas / 1000000;      

    switch(firstNumber) {
        case 1:
            person.gender = Genders::Man;
            person.dobYear = 1800;
            break;
        case 2:
            person.gender = Genders::Woman;
            person.dobYear = 1800;
            break;
        case 3:
            person.gender = Genders::Man;
            person.dobYear = 1900;
            break;
        case 4:
            person.gender = Genders::Woman;
            person.dobYear = 1900;
            break;
        case 5:
            person.gender = Genders::Man;
            person.dobYear = 2000;
            break;
        case 6:
            person.gender = Genders::Woman;
            person.dobYear = 2000;
            break;
    }

    kodas = kodas % 1000000;
    int years = kodas / 10000;

    person.dobYear += years;

    kodas = kodas % 10000;

    person.dobMonth = kodas / 100;

    kodas = kodas % 100;

    person.dobDay = kodas;

    cout << person.dobDay << endl;
    return person;
}

bool comparePerson (Person p1, Person p2) {
    if (p1.dobYear < p2.dobYear) {
        return true;
    }

    if (p1.dobYear == p2.dobYear) {
        if (p1.dobMonth < p2.dobMonth) {
            return true;
        }

        if (p1.dobMonth == p2.dobMonth) {
            if (p1.dobDay < p2.dobDay) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main () {
    ifstream kodai("kodai.txt");

    Person oldestMan;
    Person oldestWoman;

    oldestMan.dobYear = 9999;
    oldestMan.dobMonth = 9999;
    oldestMan.dobDay = 9999;

    oldestWoman.dobYear = 9999;
    oldestWoman.dobMonth = 9999;
    oldestWoman.dobDay = 9999;

    long code; 

    while (kodai >> code) {
        Person person = parsePerson(code);          

        if (person.gender == Genders::Woman) {
            if (comparePerson(person, oldestWoman)) {
                oldestWoman = person;
            }   
        } else if (person.gender == Genders::Man) {
            if (comparePerson(person, oldestMan)) {
                oldestMan = person;
            }
        }   

    }


    cout << "Oldest man: " << oldestMan.dobYear << "-" << oldestMan.dobMonth << "-" << oldestMan.dobDay << endl;
    cout << "Oldest woman: " << oldestWoman.dobYear << "-" << oldestWoman.dobMonth << "-" << oldestWoman.dobDay << endl;
}
```

Example kodai.txt:

```
33309240064
40212220064
50211020064
10001010064
20001010064
```

Can you give me any suggestions or problems that you might see?

Comment: Could you say which nation these IDs are for - or even better, reference a specification?  It appears that there's structure in the identifiers, rather than being opaque numbers as in many countries (of those that even have a concept of "National ID").

Comment: @TobySpeight Here's the documentation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Lithuania

Comment: It seems like this is a great case for [generalized minmax](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/180925/93301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Headers

Prefer `<cmath>` to `<math.h>` when writing new C++ code.  It seems it's not required in this program, so prefer to omit it instead!

`<fstream>` is only required for the test program - I'll move it to after the function.  (In fact, I'll use a string stream instead, to make the test program self-contained).

Avoid `using namespace std;`, especially in headers - there's many answers here on Code Review that explain why it's harmful.

## Types

Enumeration types are normally named as singular, unless they are intended to be combined as bitmask values.  That's a useful convention to maintain, so let's rename `Genders` to `Gender`.  We never want `Gender` to implicitly convert to and from integer values, so we can make it a strong enumeration, using `enum class`.

We can improve the cohesion of Person by observing that all its properties are derived from the ID number.  Instead of requiring client code to populate all fields, we can supply a constructor which accepts the ID number and populates the whole structure from it.

We might even choose to store only the number (to reduce the size of `Person`) and compute the derived properties when needed.  That would be an appropriate strategy if we had a much larger number of input lines.

We can present a public interface that doesn't depend on our implementation choice:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(long kodas);
    Gender gender() const;
    int dobYear() const;
    int dobMonth() const;
    int dobDay() const;
    long code() const;
};
```

I also suggest making the comparison and formatting functions into members:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(long kodas);
    Gender gender() const;
    bool older_than(const Person& other) const;
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&) const;
};
```

(Note that the birth date no longer needs to be public).

## Implementation

We don't need to split the code into year, month and day to compare - we can just sort the numbers directly (because 10000*year + 100*month + day will sort the same way).  If we did need to sort based on multiple fields, we could use `std::make_tuple()` or `std::tie()` to simplify the code.

When printing month and day, it's usual to zero-fill single-digit numbers.

We should check that we reached end-of-stream - if not, that indicates a read error, and we can't claim to have found the answer.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <iosfwd>

enum class Gender {
    Man, Woman
};

class Person
{
    long kodas;
public:
    Person(long kodas);
    Gender gender() const;
    bool older_than(const Person& other) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);

private:
    long remove_gender() const;
};
```

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
Person::Person(long kodas)
    : kodas{kodas}
{
    if (kodas < 0)
        throw std::domain_error("negative ID");
}

Gender Person::gender() const
{
    auto firstDigit = kodas / 10000000000;
    return firstDigit % 2 ? Gender::Man : Gender::Woman;
}

bool Person::older_than(const Person& other) const
{
    return remove_gender() < other.remove_gender();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p)
{
    auto n = p.remove_gender() / 10000;
    int century = 18 + n/2000000;
    n %= 1000000;

    int year = n / 10000;
    n %= 10000;

    int month = n / 100;
    int day = n % 100;

    // save stream settings
    auto fill = os.fill();

    return os << std::setfill('0')
              << century
              << std::setw(2) << year
              << '-'
              << std::setw(2) << month
              << '-'
              << std::setw(2) << day
              << std::setfill(fill);
}

long Person::remove_gender() const
{
    return gender() == Gender::Woman ? kodas - 10000000000 : kodas;
}
```

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::istringstream kodai(
                        "33309240064\n"
                        "40212220064\n"
                        "50211020064\n"
                        "10001010064\n"
                        "20001010064\n"
                        );

    Person oldestMan(99999999999);
    Person oldestWoman(89999999999);

    long code;
    while (kodai >> code) {
        Person person{code};
        switch (person.gender()) {
        case Gender::Woman:
            if (person.older_than(oldestWoman))
                oldestWoman = person;
            break;
        case Gender::Man:
            if (person.older_than(oldestMan))
                oldestMan = person;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!kodai.eof())
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read whole file");

    std::cout << "Oldest man: " << oldestMan << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Oldest woman: " << oldestWoman << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off it would have been handy to have some info about the exact format of the numbers you're dealing with.  I'll assume that you're dealing with [Lithuanian National ID Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Lithuania)(`Asmens kodas` in Lithuanian), in the format GYYMMDDNNNC.

The century of the birth year can easily be calculated backwards from the formula used to create the digit(`G = floor(year / 100) * 2 - 34 - gender`):

```
int century = ((G + (G % 2) + 34) / 2) * 100;
```

This will eliminate the whole `switch` block

I think also it would be cleaner to refactor the comparison function to return the oldest person and assign that person to the oldest person variable:

```
Person oldestPerson (Person& p1, Person& p2) {
    if(p1.dobYear < p2.dobYear)
    {
        return p1;
    }
    if(p1.dobYear == p2.dobYear)
    {
        if(p1.dobMonth < p2.dobMonth)
        {
            return p1;
        }
        if(p1.dobMonth == p2.dobMonth)
        {
            if(p1.dobDay < p2.dobDay)
            {
                return p1;
            }
        }

    }
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if there was any way to eliminate the switch block. I forgot to add the specification.

Comment: @Zygimantas - I added another thought for you